# Mouse pointer position using jquery

Tags: jquery, safari, label

Hi I am working on mouse pointer position function which is working perfectly except safari.
I am struggling with it from many hours but cant find the solution. Here is my function fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PdCxm/

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('li').click(function(e){
    var pagex= e.clientX;
    $('.radiogrup').text(pagex)
    })

})

</script>

<style>

*{ margin:0}
ul{list-style:none}

label{display:block}

li{ padding-top:5px; width:115px; border:solid 1px #FF0000}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<ul>

<li>
<label>
<input type="radio" name="test"/>
</label>
</li>

<li>
<label>
<input type="radio" name="test"/>
</label>
</li>


</ul>

<div class="radiogrup">
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i want to add current mouse position in div

Comment: seems none of programmer face this problem yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

kind of

```
var evt;
$(document).click(function(e){
    evt = e.pageX;
});
$('li').click(function(e){
    $('.radiogrup').text(evt);
});
```

little workaround:
http://jsfiddle.net/PdCxm/7/

Comment: you can calculate inside position with $('li').offset() and $(document).scrollTop(), to get inside position

Comment: yes, you are right. safari eat this click event... it's actually somehow trigger 2 click events... seems like a bug

Comment: @acrashik nice job dude...kewl

Comment: @acrashik: Can you tell me what is logic behind in your function

Comment: well :) it's simple... document click writes mouse pointer coordinates to variable... and li.click just use this value

Answer (score 0):

try `e.originalEvent.pageX or e.originalEvent.clientX` instead of `e.pageX or e.clientX`

Answer (score 0):

[Works fine in Safari](http://jsfiddle.net/SxV3P/1/) [i.e. it gives the same coords that it does in Chrome]:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><label><input type="radio" name="test"/></label></li>
    <li>a row</li>    
    <li>a row</li>    
</ul>
<div id="coords"></div>
```

​
**Javascript**

```
$(function(){
    $('li').click(function(e){

        $('#coords').html(e.clientX + " " + e.clientY);

    });
});​
```

Open console to check if anything went wrong.

Comment: I cannot change my html, label is mandatory for me, it is just not working with label else it is working fine

Comment: @amit it works using same markup you provided, check edit on the fiddle.

Comment: @amit Works fine in Safari 6.0, what's not happening in your safari?